# macOS : path MTU cache doesn't gets properly updated when pmtu discovery is set

Tags: c++, macos, networking, system-calls, mtu

I've created a virtual interface that used to get all outgoing packets, encapsulate with additional header, before resend them to their final destination through the physical adapter.

In order to choose the optimal MTU size that won't trigger fragmentation, I'd like to calculate the PMTU between the physical interface and the destination, subtracted by the encapsulation overhead. Then I'll set the virtual adapter's MTU with this result.

In order to do so, I poll the overall MTU cache using sysctl on macOS.

Here's the relevant code :

```
  size_t sz_needed = 0;
  std::vector<char> route_table;
  std::array<int, kSysctlMibLength> mib;

  mib[0] = CTL_NET;
  mib[1] = PF_ROUTE;
  mib[2] = 0;
  mib[3] = 0;
  mib[4] = NET_RT_DUMP;
  mib[5] = 0;
  // first check the size
  if (sysctl(mib.data(), kSysctlMibLength, nullptr, &sz_needed, nullptr, 0) < 0) {
    return {};
  }
  // allocate needed size for pba
  route_table.reserve(sz_needed);
  
  // than I get the route table contents 
  if (sysctl(mib.data(), kSysctlMibLength, route_table.data(), &sz_needed, nullptr, 0) < 0) {
    return {};
  }

  // now we need to get the rt_msghdr.rt_metrics.rmx_mtu /* MTU for this path */
```

Should I expect that this mtu cache gets updated automatically if the following flag is on `net.inet.tcp.path_mtu_discovery` ?

Comment: "In order to choose the optimal MTU size that won't trigger fragmentation" - How do you plan to do that? There's no way you can know what the minimum MTU size of some part of the path to the destination is. If my computer is connected to the internet via a 300baud modem with a MTU that's barely large enough to contain a IP+TCP header, then that's a valid endpoint, but you cannot know that in advance.

Comment: @JesperJuhl, thanks for the comment. I assume that my endpoint initial mtu is 1500 so I set my virtual adapter mtu to be 1500-100, where 100 is the size of the outermost header that I encapsulate every packet with. Now I want to calculate the pmtu between my endpoint phy adapter and the specific destination address is not degraded. I poll this pmtu by reading the mtu cache every minute, and if the pmtu is reduced, than I need to set my virt adapter new mtu value to pmtu-100 in order to avoid fragmantations